# How to go back to top of Programm

Tags: python

Im new to python and wrote a programm that does a+b=c and the question is, how do i do that the programm  go back to the top?

This is what i have tried but it wont open

```
#def start():
   a = int(input("num1: "))
   b = int(input("num2: "))
   c = a + b

   print("sum of {0} + {1} = {2}" .format(a, b, c))
   restart = input("Exit or Again?: ")

   if restart == "Again" or "again":
       start()
   if restart == "Exit" or "exit":
       exit
```

Had looked up a few tutorials but none of them helped.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: before def written # which defined comment. And `exit` is a function, need call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with your condition `restart == "Again" or "again"` because it is equivalent to `(restart == "Again") or "again"`. The boolean value of a string (here `again`) is True unless this string is empty. So this condition will always be `True`.

If you want to keep the same structure :

```
def start():
   a = int(input("num1: "))
   b = int(input("num2: "))
   c = a + b

   print("sum of {0} + {1} = {2}" .format(a, b, c))
   restart = input("Exit or Again?: ")

   if restart in ["Again", "again"]:
       start()
   else:
       print("Bye !")

start()
```

If you prefer to achieve it with a `while loop` :

```
restart = "again"
while restart in ["Again", "again"]:
    a = int(input("num1: "))
    b = int(input("num2: "))
    c = a + b
    print("sum of {0} + {1} = {2}" .format(a, b, c))
    restart = input("Exit or Again?: ")
```

Comment: It would be easier to check if `restart.lower() == 'again'`

Comment: True, it depends if the OP wants the input "aGaIn" to work ;)

Comment: Question: i removed the start() at the end , same thing happend as before with my old code(won't open). Why does it only work when there is a start() at the end?

Comment: `def start():` only defines your function, but it does not execute it. You need to call it by putting `start()` somewhere in the main code (outside the function definition of course)

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop.

```
again = True
while again:
    ...
    if restart.lower() == 'exit':
        again = False
```

Comment: If you included the info about why a loop is a better approach (from your comment on my answer), I think it would improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your code only defines a function. If you want to run it from command line, you need to add some code to do so.

The 2 lines I added at the bottom detect if you're running this file directly and then invoke your function. If you imported this module, the `if` would be false and the logic within the `if` would not be run.

```py
def start():
    a = int(input("num1: "))
    b = int(input("num2: "))
    c = a + b

    print("sum of {0} + {1} = {2}" .format(a, b, c))
    restart = input("Exit or Again?: ")

    if restart in ["Again", "again"]:
        start()
    else
        exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: Python doesn't call tail call optimization, so this can easily fail with the "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error. Also, the `restart == "Again" or "again"` statement is incorrect.

Comment: I'll leave it to the questioner to decide how to deal with recursion. In my mind, the question wanted a recursive answer and I think the stumbling block was that defining a function != executing a function. In any event, thanks for catching the logic error in the `if`. I only copied/pasted from the original question without proofreading it, but I have since corrected it.